"Heteroclinic orbit" for non-autonomous system?
Apologies if I am using language incorrectly, but I want to consider a non-autonomous ODE for $u(x),v(x)$ that is approximately autonomous in the limits of both $x\rightarrow\pm \infty$.
An example of the kind of ODE I am dealing with is,
$$u'=v,\quad v'= (u^2+e^x u)^2-u$$
When $x\rightarrow -\infty$, we can ignore the term with the exponential and the system  is approximately autonomous with a fixed point at $(u,v)= (1,0).$
When $x\rightarrow +\infty$, we can transform to new variables $$u=e^{-2x}\tilde{u},\quad v=e^{-2x}(\tilde{v}-2\tilde{u})$$ and the equation becomes
$$\tilde{u}'=\tilde{v},\quad \tilde{v}'= (\tilde{u}+e^{-x}\tilde{u}^2)^2-5\tilde{u}+4\tilde{v}.$$
We can again ignore the term with the exponential and it is approximately autonomous with a fixed point at $(\tilde{u},\tilde{v})= (5,0)$.
What I am wondering is what kind of method (analytic or numeric) could I use to determine whether or not there are any orbits that interpolate between these asymptotic `fixed points'? In the original $(u,v)$ variables this is an orbit that asymptotically goes to $(1,0)$ for negative $x$ and $(5 e^{-2x}, -10 e^{-2x})$ for positive $x$.
